# How can I make callback functions available to imported modules in Python?

Tags: python, import, exec, global

My problem is simple, I hope the solution is, too.

In my python application I want to select a script file and run it.

```
objcode = compile(open(self.filename).read(), os.path.basename(self.filename), "exec")
exec(objcode)
```

I want the script to be able to interact with my main application through functions that I pass in as a dictionary. Here are a couple of the functions.  BTW, Print is a lamda function, which allows me to pass arguments back and call the function that prints to my console.

```
dict = {
    "check_halt":   self.parent.check_PyScript_halt,  # Function to check if halt was pressed
    "print":        Print,      # Function that will print to command console
}
exec(objcode, dict)
```

This works fine, the script I exec can call check_halt() and print() because they live in the globals for my script.
But, if my script imports a module of utility functions I wrote, the utility functions do not have access to these callback functions, like I want them to.

I could put my utility function definitions into my script file, and then they will have access to the module globals, but I don't want to reproduce them in every script file I write.

Is there an elegant solution to this? I've even considered adding them to builtins, but I don't like that and am not sure it would work, anyway.